# C# Event Handling - Event Handler remains null

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, eventhandler

I am a beginner to C# programming.
When I run this program, the eventhandler named - `newMessagePublishedEventHandler` of the class `MessagePool` is always null while executing the `OnNewMessagePublished()` function of the same class.
Can anyone please tell me why? and also how could I resolve this?

```
namespace ConsoleApp
{
public class MessageEventArgs : System.EventArgs
{
    private int publisherId;
    private string message;

    public MessageEventArgs(int publisherId, string messageText)
    {
        this.publisherId = publisherId;
        this.message = messageText;
    }

    public int PublisherId
    {
        get { return publisherId; }
    }

    public string Message
    {
        get { return message; }
    }
}

public class Publisher
{
    private int publisherId;

    public Publisher(int publisherId)
    {
        this.publisherId = publisherId;
    }

    public int PublisherId
    {
        get { return publisherId; }
    }

    public void Publish(string message)
    {
        MessagePool.GetInstance().Publisher_PostMessage(this.publisherId, message);
        Console.WriteLine("published message - " + message);
    }
}

public class MessagePool
{
    private static MessagePool theOnlyInstanceOfMessageBroker;

    public static MessagePool GetInstance()
    {
        if (theOnlyInstanceOfMessageBroker == null)
        {
            return new MessagePool();
        }
        else
        {
            return theOnlyInstanceOfMessageBroker;
        }
    }

    private MessagePool()
    {
    }

    private EventHandler newMessagePublishedEventHandler;

    public event EventHandler NewMessagePublished
    {
        add
        {
            newMessagePublishedEventHandler += value;
        }

        remove
        {
            newMessagePublishedEventHandler -= value;
        }
    }

    public void Publisher_PostMessage(int publisherId, string message)
    {
        DateTime publishedTime = DateTime.Now;
        this.OnNewMessagePublished(publisherId, message);
    }

    private void OnNewMessagePublished(int publisherId, string message)
    {
        MessageEventArgs eventArgs = new MessageEventArgs(publisherId, message);
        if (newMessagePublishedEventHandler != null)
        {
            newMessagePublishedEventHandler(this, eventArgs);
        }
    }
}

public class Subscriber
{
    private int subscriberId;

    public Subscriber(int subscriberId)
    {
        this.subscriberId = subscriberId;
        this.SubscribeToMessagebroker();
    }

    public int SubscriberId
    {
        get { return subscriberId; }
    }

    private void SubscribeToMessagebroker()
    {
        MessagePool.GetInstance().NewMessagePublished -= Subscriber_NewMessageArrived;
        MessagePool.GetInstance().NewMessagePublished += Subscriber_NewMessageArrived;
    }

    private void Subscriber_NewMessageArrived(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (eventArgs != null && eventArgs is MessageEventArgs)
        {
            var data = eventArgs as MessageEventArgs;
            if (data != null)
                Console.WriteLine("Recieved message : '" + data.Message + "' from " + data.PublisherId);
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Subscriber subscriber = new Subscriber(1);
        Publisher publisher = new Publisher(1001);
        publisher.Publish("Hey man.. whats up?");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MessagePool` is not a proper Singleton, you are always returning a new `MessagePool`.

```
    public class MessagePool
    {
        private static MessagePool theOnlyInstanceOfMessageBroker;
        private static object _syncRoot = new object();

        public static MessagePool GetInstance()
        {
            if (theOnlyInstanceOfMessageBroker == null)
            {   
                lock(_syncRoot)
                {
                    if (theOnlyInstanceOfMessageBroker == null) 
                        theOnlyInstanceOfMessageBroker = new MessagePool();
                }
            }

            return theOnlyInstanceOfMessageBroker;

        }

        private MessagePool()
        {
        }

//...
}
```

Comment: or just `return theOnlyInstanceOfMessageBroker ?? (theOnlyInstanceOfMessageBroker = new MessagePool())`

Comment: Yes, that would work, but because he's new to C# I'd avoid the Coalesce operator :)

Comment: That's less efficient, and way more work, than just initializing the static field with the instance.

Comment: @Servy see the MS best practice here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx it says *Cases do exist, however, in which you cannot rely on the common language runtime to ensure thread safety, as in the Static Initialization example. In such cases, you must use specific language capabilities to ensure that only one instance of the object is created in the presence of multiple threads*

Comment: @RonBeyer ` When your application must delay the instantiation, use a non-default constructor or perform other tasks before the instantiation` none of those things apply, so the use of a static initializer is perfectly fine.  The article also opens by saying that it's outdated and isn't being maintained.  The static initializers in C# will run this code perfectly safely.